# Send objects through tcplistener

Tags: c#, network-programming, tcplistener

Are there any ways to send anything *besides* strings through a tcplistener?  Because all of the examples that I have seen so far involve encoding a string to an array of bytes, sending that through, and decoding it on the other side.

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("message");
//This is then sent as an array of bytes
```

What if I wanted to send a float through, or an int through, or something else?  Would this involve 'converting' an object to an array of bytes and sending that over?

[Edit]
I apologize if this is a stupid question, but I'm trying to learn more about networking here.

Comment: Have a look at the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609280/sending-and-receiving-data-over-a-network-using-tcpclient you will find an explanation with code examples on how to send data over TCP.

Comment: The examples also have shown you how to send bytes. How else could the result from GetBytes have been sent.

Comment: as [Giorgi](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31428755/) mentions you need to sent it as bytes in the end. It's what the network protocol understands. For the basic convertion though, do note that there is a [BitConverter.GetBytes(float) method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhwsaf3w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 1):

Depends, if you can attach say `BinaryWriter` to the `NetworkStream`, then you can do stuff like:

```
static void ServerTask(object clnObj)
{
    TcpClient client = clnObj as TcpClient;

    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(client.GetStream());

    int k =99;
    bw.Write(k);

    client.Close();
}
```

But when sending in binary you should be careful with things like endianness. Also with floats, important is encoding, it must be same on 
receiving and sending parts. But I think `BinaryReader`, `BinaryWriter` [handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30422556/binaryreader-binaryformatter-are-they-portable) these for you (e.g., endianness is fixed).

In the end everything is being sent as array of bytes. Just `BinaryWriter` is an abstraction here, and it does the work for you for converting the integer to array of bytes.